# Prevent fractional input C++

Tags: c++, user-input

I am completing an assignment for a class where the prompt states `Fractional scores, such as 8.3 are not allowed` 
another requirement was to not allow scores < 0 or scores >10

I think I was able to successfully make it so the program does not allow scores < 0 or scores >10 but I do not know how to not accept a fractional score

```
int getJudgeData(string judge)
{
    double input = -1;
    while ( input < 0 || input > 10 )
    {
        cout << "Enter the score from " << judge <<endl;
        cin >> input;
    }
return input;
}
```

Is it possible to only accept whole numbers while limiting the input to 0-10

Comment: Why not simply declare input as `int`?

Comment: You're returning an int from the function, so I'm puzzled as to why you're reading a double from the input stream.

Comment: I have attempted to change input as `int` but if i were to enter a number such as 8.3 the application will continuously ask for the judge 2 score http://i.imgur.com/byou7DQ.png

Comment: @user3363195: And if you were to enter a number such as "AZQ" (which is just as much a number as `8.3` is a whole number between 0 and 10), the application would do the same thing.  Use `int`, and add error recovery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int getJudgeData(string judge)
{
    double input = -1;
    while( input < 0 || input > 10 || (input - (int)input) > 0 )
    {
        cout << "Enter the score from " << judge <<endl;
        cin >> input;
    }
    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:-

```
if (floor(input) == input)
   //number is not fractional.
```

to rule out fractions...